# Does a relationship between missing values indicate MNAR?

Tags: classification, missing-data, data-imputation, mnar

I have a dataset where several features are missing values only if another feature is also missing a value. Does this indicate that the missing data is missing not at random (MNAR)? Additionally, how does this affect my next steps in regard to dealing with the missing data? It is my understanding that MNAR data is quite hard to deal with and that imputation methods can be unreliable. My thought was to impute the values and leave a feature that indicates how many missing values exist for that observation.

Comment: Sounds like you need to develop a causal model to guide your statistical modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Identifying the Threat

We first need to identify what source of missingness we have here, which I briefly summarize:

- Missing completely at random (MCAR): missingness you truly don't know the source of (which doesn't apply here). Generally you should just handle this kind of data with modern methods like FIML or MI, but that doesn't appear to be relevant to your issue.
- Missing at random (MAR): missingness that is due to a predictable reason not related to a subject and therefore easily estimated as a random effect (for example, the effect of religiosity on reporting sexual activity). *This requires special attention*.
- Missing not at random (MNAR): missing due to a subject level variable (more consumed alcohol leads to less reporting of it due to social desirability bias). *As above, you need to do some detective work here if this is true*.

Yours sounds like the MAR case. Clearly there is some other variable influencing the outcome, and this is definitely important to consider. Somebody already mentioned that building a causal model may help answer this to a degree. One way of doing this is employing some kind of directed acrylic graph (DAG), summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). One way of modeling this is treating the missingness factor as a kind of "toggled switch", which we can turn on and turn off in order to influence the variable you are worried about. [This guide](https://cameronpatrick.com/post/2023/06/untangling-mar-mcar-mnar/) specifically highlights how to do accomplish this with respect to missing data and has [a paper](https://www.jclinepi.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0895-4356%2821%2900010-X) (Lee et al., 2021) which includes real world guides for dealing with this, including this useful example of a DAG with missingness models:

[image]

You may not know the full scope of your missingness, and its important to investigate this before moving further (you may have a case where $X$ influences missingness in $Z$ which in turn influences missingness in $Y$). One way to achieve this is with a missingness pattern map, shown below.

[image]

Here we see each row by column number of missing patterns (the block of missingness occurring in the red portions). If we have a case of two or more blocks with missingness, this usually indicates that there may be some relationship in the missingness between variables you should look further into.

##### Attacking the Problem

Of course all of this is useless if we don't know what to do with it. Here are some options:

- **Eliminate the "dumb culprits"**. Sometimes your missingness may be something you didn't expect and completely healable. I once worked through a dataset that had a baffling amount of missingness and was shocked anybody used it. Upon further inspection, I realized that R had coded the missingness wrong (I think it was an artefact from the SPSS data I was handed but can't recall exactly why). In any case it was completely fixable and immediately solved the problem, so don't forget to check for stuff like this.
- **Conduct a sensitivity analysis**. Missingness is most problematic when it exceeds around 5% (Little et al., 2014). Once it escapes this threshold, running a sensitivity analysis will showcase how much this influences your estimates. It may not matter at all. It may matter a lot. This analysis will at least provide some insight.
- **Directly model it using a random effects structure**. I have seen some papers that actually use random effects regression models to deal with this issue. Here is an example using [linear mixed models](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/hec.4510) and this is one I recently discovered for [generalized additive models](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/missing.data.html). It may require some sophisticated coding but may at least give you some way to dance around your missingness.
- **When all else fails, use MI/FIML**. I know I just contradicted myself by saying you shouldn't do this unless the data is MCAR. However, MI can potentially reduce bias in the estimates *to a degree* if there is no other option available, but it does come with some limitations you may need to document if this is for a manuscript (Little et al., 2014).
- **For the love of all that is holy, do not use listwise deletion**. With very minor missingness (some oddball two or three cases), this isn't an issue. However, you would be surprised how many people run a regression and don't even realize the defaults tossed out hundreds of observations in the process. Literally any other option is better than this. Please consider the above options before moving further.

##### References

- Lee, K. J., Tilling, K. M., Cornish, R. P., Little, R. J. A., Bell, M. L., Goetghebeur, E., Hogan, J. W., & Carpenter, J. R. (2021). Framework for the treatment and reporting of missing data in observational studies: The Treatment And Reporting of Missing data in Observational Studies framework. Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, 134, 79–88. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2021.01.008
- Little, T. D., Jorgensen, T. D., Lang, K. M., & Moore, E. W. G. (2014). On the joys of missing data. Journal of Pediatric Psychology, 39(2), 151–162. https://doi.org/10.1093/jpepsy/jst048

Answer (score 0):

There are technical definitions of MAR/MNAR and software for 'refuting' MAR. I am no expert but I believe MAR requires independence of $X$ (when it exists) from whether or not $Y$ exists. If you created an indicator variable for your missing data (such that values always existed) then technically you would have a variable that refutes MAR. I'd call that MNAR.